# swift ReactiveCocoa combineLatest

Tags: swift, reactive-cocoa

in obj-c, I can use this method:

```
RACSignal *signUpActiveSignal = [RACSignal combineLatest:@[validUsernameSignal, validPasswordSignal]
                reduce:^id(NSNumber*usernameValid, NSNumber *passwordValid){
                  return @([usernameValid boolValue]&&[passwordValid boolValue]);
                }];
```

when i translate it to swift, like this:

```
RACSignal.combineLatest([accountSignal, passwordSignal]) { () -> AnyObject! in
        // arguments
        return true
        }.subscribeNext { (reduceResult: AnyObject!) -> Void in
        KMLog("\(reduceResult)")
    }
```

how can i get the parameters

Comment: Which parameters? Please elaborate on your question

Comment: In swift do you use the old RAC2 or the swift integration development branch?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't been able to figure out how to use that closure for a `combineLatest`, but you *can* use `map`. The input is an `RACTuple` object. You can get the objects from the input signals like this:

```
RACSignal.combineLatest([accountSignal, passwordSignal]).map {
        let tuple = $0 as! RACTuple
        let account = tuple.first as! String
        let password = tuple.second as! String
        // your code here
    }
```

Obviously you'll want to cast your objects to their actual types, but I just used Strings here as an example. And remember that you'll have to return the combined object at the end of the `map` closure.

Comment: I use this method and this method was not invoked RACSignal.combineLatest([phoneNumEdit.rac_textSignal(), passportEdit.rac_textSignal()]).map {
            let tuple = $0 as! RACTuple
            let account = tuple.first as! String